# Adobe premiere Pro: timecode not synchronize

Tags: premiere, adobe, timecode

I trying to add a timecode to my video but the timer is not synchronise with the video time

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Code temporel is pretty buggy. Try to chante the setting which now says Média. If this doesn't help, nest the video and try again

Comment: My video is 15 i/s but timecode only allow a minimum of 24 i/s, wtf is this software ?